# Python: create a list of separate texts from a text file that contains several texts

Tags: python, list, text

I have a .txt file which contains 4 texts and I'd like to create a list in which all the for texts will appear on a new line - thus I'll have 4 objects in a list. The code should say something: read the text line by line (but append the lines within a doc), but as soon as you get to '1 doc of x' start a new line. I've tried the following, which does not create what I want:

```
with open('testfile.txt') as f:

    myList = f.readlines()

myList = [x.strip() for x in content]
```

***testfile.txt***

```
1 doc of 4

Hello World. 
This is another question


2 doc of 4

This is a new text file. 
Not much in it.

3 doc of 4

This is the third text. 
It contains separate info.

4 doc of 4

The final text. 
A short one.
```

***expected output for myList:***

```
myList=['Hello World. This is another question',

        'This is a new text file. Not much in it.',

        'This is the third text. It contains separate info.',

        'The final text. A short one.']
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

Something like this will do – it *will* crash miserably if the document does not start with a header line, though.

```
import re

# This will hold each document as a list of lines.
# To begin with, there are no documents.
myList = []

# Define a regular expression to match header lines.
header_line_re = re.compile(r'\d+ doc of \d+')

with open('testfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:  # For each line...
        line = line.strip()  # Remove leading and trailing whitespace
        if header_line_re.match(line):  # If the line matches the header line regular expression...
            myList.append([])  # Start a new group within `myList`,
            continue  # then skip processing the line further.
        if line:  # If the line is not empty, simply add it to the last group.
            myList[-1].append(line)

# Recompose the lines back to strings (separated by spaces, not newlines).
myList = [' '.join(doc) for doc in myList]

print(myList)
```

The output is:

```
[
    "Hello World. This is another question",
    "This is a new text file. Not much in it.",
    "This is the third text. It contains separate info.",
    "The final text. A short one.",
]
```

Comment: Well, it does work on my testfile.txt, but not on the one that has 145 texts. How do I add a header line please? What the header line means? Google is not of help... Thanks.

Comment: @AndreaErőss Your example has these lines "3 doc of 4" -- the code expects lines like that (e.g. `1953 doc of 4911`) to appear between documents.

Comment: Thanks AKX so much, all my respect to your knowledge. I hope there won't be an issue that the texts now appear between " " and not ' '. I'm conducting sentiment analysis.